# Partitioning and grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I am trying to calculate something in Power BI or SQL, as this is conserning many many millions of rows, performance leads me to doing this in SQL, But i've been trying to get this work for quite a while already!

I am trying to make a calculate column that shows the current state of an account

| AccountId | PartnerId | Transactions | FirstTransaction | row_num | Industry | Private/Public | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6906 | 19 | 557 | 01-Jan-22 | 1 | Financial services | Private | Private Only |
| 6906 | 20 | 557 | 02-Jan-22 | 2 | Financial services | Private | Private Only |
| 6906 | 32 | 30 | 05-Jan-22 | 3 | Government | Public | Public + Private |
| 6906 | 738 | 2 | 12-Jan-22 | 4 | Government | Public | Public + Private |
| 6906 | 82 | 5 | 13-Jan-22 | 5 |  | Private | Public + Private |
| 6906 | 74 | 1 | 11-Jun-22 | 6 | Financial services | Private | Public + Private |
| 6906 | 56 | 1 | 27-Jun-22 | 7 | Insurance | Private | Public + Private |

The result should check if an account has Public or Private transactions, in order of occurrence. I added a rank, partitioned by accountid and ordered by date  ( = row_num)
But next I would want a column that can crosscheck all the values within a partition.

In this example above, This account has the label "Private Only" on 01-01 as it only has done transactions with a private partner. the second line also says Private only, as it still has only done transactions with a private partner. But as of the third line it changes to Public + Private as it also used public transactions.

Anyone an idea how I can calcualte that Result column?

Edit:
My Original Query:

```
  SELECT ua.[AccountId],
      ua.[PartnerId],
      i.industry,
      i.[Public/Private],
      COUNT(*) AS Transactions,
      MIN(ua.[FilepathDate]) AS FirstTransaction,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY accountid
                         ORDER BY MIN(ua.[FilepathDate] )) 
Partner_row_num

 FROM [dbo].[incremental_UserActions] ua
 INNER JOIN tmp_Industry i ON ua.partnerid = i.partnerid
 WHERE YEAR(ua.[FilepathDate]) = 2022
   AND ua.accountid = 6906
 GROUP BY ua.[AccountId],
        ua.[PartnerId],
        i.industry,
        i.[Public/Private]
```

Edit 2 :
the eventual output of the above looks like this :

```
    | AccountId | FirstTransaction | MonthAgg   | Result            |
| --------- | ---------------- | ---------- | ----------------- |
| 7015      | 05/01/2022       | 01/01/2022 | FAS Only          |
| 7015      | 06/01/2022       | 01/01/2022 | FAS + Other Public|
| 7015      | 19/01/2022       | 01/01/2022 | Public + Private  |
| 7015      | 19/01/2022       | 01/01/2022 | Public + Private  |
| 7015      | 24/01/2022       | 01/01/2022 | Public + Private  |
| 7015      | 08/04/2022       | 01/04/2022 | Public + Private  |
| 7015      | 08/06/2022       | 01/06/2022 | Public + Private  |
| 7799      | 04/01/2022       | 01/01/2022 | Private Only      |
| 7799      | 10/01/2022       | 01/01/2022 | Public + Private  |
| 7799      | 08/03/2022       | 01/03/2022 | Public + Private  |
| 7799      | 08/04/2022       | 01/04/2022 | Public + Private  |
| 7799      | 17/12/2022       | 01/12/2022 | Public + Private  |
```

The final result should have consecutive months per accountid.
so 1 line per account per month

```
| AccountId | FirstTransaction | MonthAgg   | Result           |
| --------- | ---------------- | ---------- | ---------------- |
| 7015      | 24/01/2022       | 01/01/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7015      | 24/01/2022       | 01/02/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7015      | 24/01/2022       | 01/03/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7015      | 08/04/2022       | 01/04/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7015      | 08/04/2022       | 01/05/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7015      | 08/06/2022       | 01/06/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7015      | 08/06/2022       | 01/07/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7015      | 08/06/2022       | 01/08/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7015      | 08/06/2022       | 01/09/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7015      | 08/06/2022       | 01/10/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7015      | 08/06/2022       | 01/11/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7015      | 08/06/2022       | 01/12/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7799      | 10/01/2022       | 01/01/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7799      | 10/01/2022       | 01/02/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7799      | 08/03/2022       | 01/03/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7799      | 08/04/2022       | 01/04/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7799      | 08/04/2022       | 01/05/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7799      | 08/04/2022       | 01/06/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7799      | 08/04/2022       | 01/07/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7799      | 08/04/2022       | 01/08/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7799      | 08/04/2022       | 01/09/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7799      | 08/04/2022       | 01/10/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7799      | 08/04/2022       | 01/11/2022 | Public + Private |
| 7799      | 17/12/2022       | 01/12/2022 | Public + Private |
```

Comment: Edited Orginal Post !

Comment: Seems like you want a (windowed) conditional `COUNT` here, so that you can count if any rows had `'Private'`/`'Public'` for `[Public/Private]`. Then you can use a `CASE` expression to return the value you want.

Comment: Well I know how those work, but how the implement this in my query ? :)

Comment: This would be easier for us if you provided sample data. The data you've given us is your expected results so we can;t run your query against it (especially when it references 2 tables and we only have 1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions. If there are only two possible values in the `[Public/Private]` column, then, starting from your existing query:

```
SELECT ua.[AccountId],
    ua.[PartnerId],
    i.industry,
    i.[Public/Private],
    COUNT(*) AS Transactions,
    MIN(ua.[FilepathDate]) AS FirstTransaction,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY accountid ORDER BY MIN(ua.[FilepathDate] )) Partner_row_numn,
    CASE WHEN MIN(i.[Public/Private]) OVER((PARTITION BY accountid ORDER BY MIN(ua.[FilepathDate]))
            = MAX(i.[Public/Private]) OVER((PARTITION BY accountid ORDER BY MIN(ua.[FilepathDate]))
        THEN concat( MIN(i.[Public/Private]) OVER((PARTITION BY accountid ORDER BY MIN(ua.[FilepathDate])), ' Only')
        ELSE 'Public + Private'
    END AS Result
FROM [dbo].[incremental_UserActions] ua
INNER JOIN tmp_Industry i ON ua.partnerid = i.partnerid
WHERE YEAR(ua.[FilepathDate]) = 2022 AND ua.accountid = 6906
GROUP BY ua.[AccountId], ua.[PartnerId], i.industry, i.[Public/Private]
```

The idea is to compare the MIN and MAX values; if they are the same, then it means there is only one distinct value in the window - else there are two different values, so we just use the mixed tag.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
with cte as
( 
  select *,
  (case when lag(private_public)over(partition by accountid order by row_num)<>private_public then 1 else 0 end)status
  from accounts
)
select AccountId, PartnerId, Transactions, FirstTransaction, row_num, Industry, Private_Public,(case when sum(status)over(partition by accountid order by row_num)>0 then 'Private + Public' else Private_Public +' only' end) Result from cte
```

Output:

| AccountId | PartnerId | Transactions | FirstTransaction | row_num | Industry | Private_Public | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6906 | 19 | 557 | 2022-01-01 | 1 | Financial services | Private | Private only |
| 6906 | 20 | 557 | 2022-01-02 | 2 | Financial services | Private | Private only |
| 6906 | 32 | 30 | 2022-01-05 | 3 | Government | Public | Private + Public |
| 6906 | 738 | 2 | 2022-01-12 | 4 | Government | Public | Private + Public |
| 6906 | 82 | 5 | 2022-01-13 | 5 | *null* | Private | Private + Public |
| 6906 | 74 | 1 | 2022-06-11 | 6 | Financial services | Private | Private + Public |
| 6906 | 56 | 1 | 2022-06-27 | 7 | Insurance | Private | Private + Public |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NZK90VUn)

Comment: Great! 
Looks like I was able to use this example!
I am now still stuck on 1 item. 

I would also need the output to have 1 line per account per month in the year 2022. 
It seems that synapse serverless does not support recursive CTE's, so I'm a bit lost on how to continue.. once again :p

The filling months should have all values from the previous available value

Comment: Please share your desired output data sample for that

Comment: Updated my original post again! Thx

Comment: That's not recursive.

Comment: @shawnt00 not, it's not.

Comment: @Kazi, my comment refers back to the earlier comment that recursive queries are not supported.

Comment: aah ok, well I know its not supported! :D 
My question was how I can get this result, without writing a recursive statement :/

Comment: @RobbeVL is it always one year (12 months per accountid) of data?

Comment: @RobbeVL, the query above is not recursive. That feature/limitation is irrelevant.

Comment: It should indeed always be 12 months! @KaziMohammadAliNur

Comment: I have added another answer. Please check. If the answer helped you please accept it.

Comment: I get this error : 
Msg 15816, Level 16, State 2, Line 17
The query references an object that is not supported in distributed processing mode.

Same one with Recursive CTE I used... So i'm guessing more limitations

Answer (score 0):

I have created a months table and inserted 12 months in it. Then I have joined it with previous result. No recursion is needed. Please check.

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    AccountId INT NOT NULL,
    PartnerId INT NOT NULL,
    Transactions INT NOT NULL,
    FirstTransaction DATE NOT NULL,
    row_num INT NOT NULL,
    Industry VARCHAR(50),
    Private_Public VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL    
);
```

```
INSERT INTO accounts (AccountId, PartnerId, Transactions, FirstTransaction, row_num, Industry, Private_Public)
VALUES 
    (6905, 19, 557, '2022-01-01', 1, 'Financial services', 'Private'),
    (6906, 20, 557, '2022-01-02', 2, 'Financial services', 'Private'),
    (6906, 32, 30, '2022-01-05', 3, 'Government', 'Public'),
    (6906, 738, 2, '2022-01-12', 4, 'Government', 'Public'),
    (6906, 82, 5, '2022-01-13', 5, NULL, 'Private'),
    (6905, 74, 1, '2022-06-11', 6, 'Financial services', 'public'),
    (6906, 56, 1, '2022-06-27', 7, 'Insurance', 'Private');
```

```
create table months(monthId int,name varchar(50),first_day date);
INSERT INTO months (monthId, name, first_day) VALUES
(1, 'January', '2023-01-01'),
(2, 'February', '2023-02-01'),
(3, 'March', '2023-03-01'),
(4, 'April', '2023-04-01'),
(5, 'May', '2023-05-01'),
(6, 'June', '2023-06-01'),
(7, 'July', '2023-07-01'),
(8, 'August', '2023-08-01'),
(9, 'September', '2023-09-01'),
(10, 'October', '2023-10-01'),
(11, 'November', '2023-11-01'),
(12, 'December', '2023-12-01');
```

```
Query:

with cte as
( 
  select *,
  (case when lag(private_public)over(partition by accountid order by row_num)<>private_public then 1 else 0 end)status,
  row_number()over(partition by accountId,month(FirstTransaction) order by FirstTransaction desc)ReverseTranSeq
  from accounts
)
,finalCte as
(
  select  AccountId, PartnerId, Transactions, FirstTransaction, row_num, Industry, Private_Public,(case when sum(status)over(partition by accountid order by row_num)>0 then 'Private + Public' else Private_Public +' only' end) Result 
  from cte 
  where ReverseTranSeq=1
)
  select m.AccountId, 
  max(FirstTransaction) over(partition by m.AccountId order by first_day  rows between unbounded preceding and current row)FirstTransaction,
  first_day MonthAgg,
  last_value(Result)ignore nulls over(partition by m.accountId order by first_day rows between unbounded preceding and current row)Result
from months cross join (select distinct AccountId from cte  )m
left join finalCte 
  on finalCte.AccountId=m.AccountId and months.monthId=month(finalCte.FirstTransaction)  
order by m.AccountId,months.monthId
```

OUtput:

| AccountId | FirstTransaction | MonthAgg | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6905 | 2022-01-01 | 2023-01-01 | Private only |
| 6905 | 2022-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | Private only |
| 6905 | 2022-01-01 | 2023-03-01 | Private only |
| 6905 | 2022-01-01 | 2023-04-01 | Private only |
| 6905 | 2022-01-01 | 2023-05-01 | Private only |
| 6905 | 2022-06-11 | 2023-06-01 | Private + Public |
| 6905 | 2022-06-11 | 2023-07-01 | Private + Public |
| 6905 | 2022-06-11 | 2023-08-01 | Private + Public |
| 6905 | 2022-06-11 | 2023-09-01 | Private + Public |
| 6905 | 2022-06-11 | 2023-10-01 | Private + Public |
| 6905 | 2022-06-11 | 2023-11-01 | Private + Public |
| 6905 | 2022-06-11 | 2023-12-01 | Private + Public |
| 6906 | 2022-01-13 | 2023-01-01 | Private + Public |
| 6906 | 2022-01-13 | 2023-02-01 | Private + Public |
| 6906 | 2022-01-13 | 2023-03-01 | Private + Public |
| 6906 | 2022-01-13 | 2023-04-01 | Private + Public |
| 6906 | 2022-01-13 | 2023-05-01 | Private + Public |
| 6906 | 2022-06-27 | 2023-06-01 | Private + Public |
| 6906 | 2022-06-27 | 2023-07-01 | Private + Public |
| 6906 | 2022-06-27 | 2023-08-01 | Private + Public |
| 6906 | 2022-06-27 | 2023-09-01 | Private + Public |
| 6906 | 2022-06-27 | 2023-10-01 | Private + Public |
| 6906 | 2022-06-27 | 2023-11-01 | Private + Public |
| 6906 | 2022-06-27 | 2023-12-01 | Private + Public |

```
[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aUd6k79t)
```